# How to fold all org blocks under the current header line?

Tags: org-mode

**Q:** how do I hide all `org-mode` blocks under the current
header?

I want to fold all source code blocks *under the current heading
only*.  I know that I can use `org-hide-block-all` to fold
*all* blocks in the buffer, and `org-hide-block-toggle` to toggle
the *current* block (i.e., the one at point).  But how about all
blocks under the current heading?

For example:

```
* header 1
   #+name: block-1
   #+begin_src R
     x <- 1:10
   #+end_src
   #+name: block-2
   #+begin_src R
     y <- 1:10
   #+end_src
   #+name: block-3
   #+begin_src R
     z <- x + y
   #+end_src
* header 2
   #+name: dont-fold-me-1
   #+begin_src R
     a <- "puppies"
   #+end_src
   #+name: dont-fold-me-2
   #+begin_src R
     b <- "kitties"
   #+end_src
```

I'd like to be able to fold all blocks under `header 1` but leave
the rests of the blocks (under `header 2`) alone.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using buffer narrowing?

```el
(defun my/org-hide-block-subtree ()
  "Hide blocks only below current heading."
  (interactive)
  (save-restriction
    (widen)
    (org-narrow-to-subtree)
    (org-hide-block-all)))
```

It's situations like this that I wish `org-map-entries` could map over more than just headings...

Comment: Thanks!  I made a minor edit to use the `save-restriction` idiom.  Feel free to roll it back if you prefer.

Comment: Great suggestion!  `save-restriction` was new to me :-)